# Problem in layer overlapping (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, layers, gps

I want to plot GPS points on QGIS (version 2.14.1). I have added the vector layer of SE Asian countries, and added the delimited text layer of my GPS points which included species name, lat and lon. Unfortunately the two layers do not overlap at all. I have used the same projection system for both layers (WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator), and I have checked the GPS points using the coordinate capture function in QGIS, it gives the similar points for that area I have in the delimited text document. How can I make them overlap?

Comment: GPS is usually WGS 84 (not mercator). Can you zoom on each layer individually and tell what the values of the coordinates are ?

Comment: Things get weird now....my gps pts have the correct lat and lon (123, 09), but the SE map doesnt (now goes up to 8-digit coordinates....)......

Comment: what is your delimiter ?

Comment: I used .csv as delimited file

Comment: Is this what you mean by delimiter?

Comment: well, it seems that qgis is not reading your delimited text layer properly, so maybe you could modifiy the delimiter in your text layer (using ";", for instance. )

Comment: Can you give an example of your coordinates?